# Pytorch BCELoss function different outputs for same inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to calculate cross entropy loss using pytorch's BCELoss Function for a binary classification problem. While tinkering I found this weird behaviour.

```
from torch import nn
sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()
loss = nn.BCELoss(reduction="sum")
target = torch.tensor([0., 1.])

input1 = torch.tensor([1., 1.], requires_grad=True)
input2 = sigmoid(torch.tensor([10., 10.], requires_grad=True))
print(input2) #tensor([1.0000, 1.0000], grad_fn=<SigmoidBackward>)

print(loss(input1, target)) #tensor(100., grad_fn=<BinaryCrossEntropyBackward>)
print(loss(input2, target)) #tensor(9.9996, grad_fn=<BinaryCrossEntropyBackward>)
```

Since both input1 and input2 have same value, shouldn't it return the same loss value instead of 100 and 9.9996. The correct loss value should be 100 since I am multiplying log(0) ~-infinity which is capped at -100 in pytorch. https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCELoss.html

What is going on here and where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sigmoid(10)` is not exactly equal to 1:

```py
>>> 1 / (1 + torch.exp(-torch.tensor(10.))).item()
0.9999545833234493
```

In your case:

```py
>>> sigmoid(torch.tensor([10., 10.], requires_grad=True)).tolist()
[0.9999545812606812, 0.9999545812606812]
```

Thus `input1` is not the same as `input2`: `[1.0, 1.0]` vs `[0.9999545812606812, 0.9999545812606812]`,

Let's compute BCE manually:

```py
def bce(x, y):
    return - (y * torch.log(x) + (1 - y) * torch.log(1 - x)).item()


# input1

x1 = torch.tensor(1.)
x2 = torch.tensor(1.)

y1 = torch.tensor(0.)
y2 = torch.tensor(1.)


print("input1:", sum([bce(x1, y1), bce(x2, y2)]))


# input2

x1 = torch.tensor(0.9999545812606812)
x2 = torch.tensor(0.9999545812606812)

y1 = torch.tensor(0.)
y2 = torch.tensor(1.)


print("input2:", sum([bce(x1, y1), bce(x2, y2)]))


input1: nan
input2: 9.999631525119185
```

For `input1` we get `nan`, but according to docs:

> Our solution is that BCELoss clamps its log function outputs to be greater than or equal to -100. This way, we can always have a finite loss value and a linear backward method.

That's why we have `100` in a final `pytorch`'s `BCE` output.

Comment: Thank you. But this `input3 = torch.tensor([0.9999545812606812, 0.9999545812606812], requires_grad=True)
print(loss(input, target))' returns 100 and I understand this result but how am I getting 9.9996 as asked in the question.

Comment: Are you sure? in a provided code you used `input`:  `print(loss(input, target)` not `input3`

Comment: I just created a new variable input3 with the sigmoid output to test the loss function as mentioned in your answer and got the reliable result. But the code snippet I have in the question still gives 9.9996 while trying with input2. Am I missing somethig. Thank you.